# Transform or Transforms?

Tags: grammar, descriptive-grammar

Is this sentence grammatically correct?

"It can melt away anger and transforms your bad mood into a good mood."

I am confused between transform and transforms.

Comment: The reason it's ungrammatical is that it has a coordination of verb phrases governed by the modal "can", and hence requires infinitival VPs as its  complement: _It can [melt away anger] and [**transform** your bad mood into a good mood_].

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sentence as written is not *unconditionally* ungrammatical, but it is only grammatical when it is understood as expressing an unusual idea that you are unlikely to want to express.

"It can melt away anger and transforms your bad mood into a good mood" uses the conjunction *and* to coordinate the two finite verb phrases "can melt away anger" and "transforms your bad mood into a good mood". This means that in  this sentence, the auxiliary verb "can" (which expresses a sense of possibility or uncertainty) goes with only the verb "melt".

But it doesn't make much sense to only have uncertainty about the first part of the sentence. As written, the sentence seems to mean "It's possible that it will melt away anger. Also, it will transform your bad mood into a good mood (no matter what)." That is, it seems to imply that maybe, your bad mood will transform into a good mood but your anger will not melt away. But it seems more likely that what you really want to say is that "It's possible that it will melt away anger. Also, it's possible that it will transform your bad mood into a good mood."

In order to ensure that the scope of the auxiliary *can* covers both parts of the sentence, you must put the verb *tranform* into the infinitive form. The resulting sentence ("It can melt away anger and transform your bad mood into a good mood") uses the conjunction *and* to coordinate the two non-finite verb phrases "melt away anger" and "transform your good mood into a bad mood". According to comments by BillJ, in this construction the auxiliary verb *can* governs both verb phrases, so both *melt* and *tranform* must take the infinitive form.

Comment: Yes: it's a coordination of two VPs as complement of "can", and hence requires the plain form verbs "melt" and "transform".

Comment: I'd say that "can" governs both VPs, and hence the latter must be infinitivals.

Comment: Thanks Sumelic.
It is a well-explained answer.

Answer (score 1):

The sentence as written isn't correct.

Depending on what is being communicated, there are two possible ways of rephrasing it:

> It can melt away anger and <sup><s>it can</s></sup> *transform* your bad mood into a good mood.
>   It can melt away anger, and *it transforms* your bad mood into a good mood.

While either form is grammatical, I would say the first—with the singular *transform*—is the more likely and natural of the two. Although *it can* can be added, its elision is fine.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification Jason.